# Redirecting path in ReactJS's react-router-dom's route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I declare two different paths for the same component by using an array.

```
        <Router>    
          <HeaderBN/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path={["/about", "/aboutus"]} component={About}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

But now I want to if anybody visit '/about' path then he would be redirected to '/aboutus' path automatically. How can I do this? I read react-router-dom documentation but didn't find any way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take out `about` from the array and create a new route with redirect logic inside of it.

```
 <Route exact path="/about">
     <Redirect to="/aboutus" />
  </Route>
```